# Изменяющийся пароль при авторизации

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
<?php include ("bd.php");

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
exit();
}
else
{
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
}
$query = "SELECT a23,code_a FROM admin WHERE a22='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
$lst = @mysql_query($query);
$a23_passw= mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'a23' );
$admin= mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'code_a' );

if (!$lst)
{
Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
exit();
}
if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0)
{
Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
exit();
}
$a23 =  @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $a23_passw)
{
Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
exit();
}
}
?>
```

Это содержимое файла я includ'ю, в каждый файл для авторизации. Суть, думаю, понятна, `a23` - логин, `a24` - пароль, `admin` - ну это кое-что, что нужно, и не надо удалять.

Хотел бы узнать про одно извращение. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы человек, входящий под своим логином, в качестве пароля вводил свой пароль + 1 цифру, которая равна дню недели?

Скажем, в таблице записано: `ivan, 123`. Таблицу мы не переписываем ни в коем случае. Чтобы `ivan`'у зайти в понедельник - нужно ввести `1231`, во вторник - `1232` и т.д., в воскресенье - `1237`. Подскажите, как такое сделать?

p.s. Если кто даст пару аргументированных советов по самому коду, буду признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])

так лучше не делать, пароли надо хранить в [md5](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), то есть

> md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])

и затем сравнивать с хэшем в базе данных, как то так

> $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
>
> if ($pass ==$a23_passw) {echo 'совпадение есть!';}

соответственно, если вы хотите чтобы юзер вводил цифру недели - вам надо вначале файла авторизации определить день недели, и определить какое для него должно быть сегодня число.

В вашем случае, нужно обработать переменную пост, выбрав последний символ в ней, и соответственно получить две переменные:

1. сам пароль
2. последняя цифра (день недели)

Сделать это можно с помощью функции [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Есть еще вариант, на мой взгляд он более оптимален и менее затратен:
сделать два поля - одно под пароль, второе под день недели, но это уже вам решать.

По поводу кода: ужасно нечитаем, а так как ужасно нечитаем - что там еще на так - сложно сказать )

Comment: и кстати, зачем приводить к виду 
>$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
вообще, лучшее погуглите http://zavu.ru/n9asqVg/ решение с сессиями

Comment: вот кстати [нарыл][1],
в соседней теме давал.


[1]: http://zavu.ru/itqCoT2/